# Event listener on click on loop

Tags: javascript, loops, click, dom-events

I'm trying to detect a click event on an dom element inside an array.

What I did so far, but it runs the loop before I even click.

```
for (var i = 0, len = block.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  block[i].addEventListener("click", blockIt());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I just want to detect the click on the element I click that is in the array, so later I can look at the value and pass different functions depending of the value..

Comment: `block[i].addEventListener("click", blockIt);` ?

Answer (score 2):

You're immediately calling the function. Change that to

```
for (var i = 0, len = block.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  block[i].addEventListener("click", blockIt); // no parenthesis here
}
```